# How to upload the implemneted "in App" into AppStore?

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have done the necessary coding for inApp purchase and i checked it in the sandbox environment and it is working well . but when i upload the project i don't know how to attach the inApp that i added in the iTunes. After i uploaded my inApp status is same as before , it says "Ready to submit". Below is the image of my inApp status that i used in my app.

[image]

can anyone please tell me how to solve this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Didnt you find in the top of page inside the InApplication Manager-> your application as "submit to itunes" like that. After submitting your status will change to "Waiting for review"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Haven't uploaded your app binary, there's an option of adding In-App Purchases in the App Details in iTunes Connect. So your Product ID/Reference Name will appear in the In-App options of the App.

But

If you've already submitted your app, you cannot implement In-App Purchase in your released app. It has to be "attached" or added in a new binary and re-submitted.

Comment: My project is still in "waiting for review" . is it possible to resubmit it now

Comment: yep..you can use the option of DEVELOPER REJECT..that is reject your binary yourself and re-submit your binary with IAP enabled.

Comment: Goto manage your applications in iTunes Connect..Click on your app there..there'll be an option called VIEW DETAILS below your app icon in VERSION DETAILS..click on VIEW DETAILS..scroll down in the resulting screen and you'll find an option of IN-APP PURCHASES..click on Edit and add your IAP in the popup window..Save and Click on Ready to upload binary..upload your app then and you're through..

Keep in mind that you have to developer-reject your current in-review app first..

Comment: please tick the answer, if it has satisfied ur query.

Answer (score 1):

As you have tested the IAP with sandbox environment, now in the edit option you will be able to see the In App Products. Select the products which you wan to add with the application. Then click on ready to submit, you products will be ready with the binary. Upload the binary and then every thing will be in review process.